# starting up roscore automatically on boot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I have got a basic ROS running on a some hardware successfully, thanks to helpful pointers from this community (love you guys for that). Right now I am facing another seemingly difficult issue. I am trying to get the roscore process to autostart at boot so that I can get my robot to move about freely in the room. I have tried updating rc.local, crontab, and init.d update and also the autologin script. All of them fail to work. I am using Raspberry Pi hardware with raspbian wheezy linux and I need to start roscore as root on this hardware at boot up automatically. Please guide me towards accomplishing this.

Thanks and Regards to all,
Praseen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75727/starting-up-roscore-automatically-on-boot/) by [Praseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5042/praseen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2013-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find quite similar question if you scroll main page a little down. Please see [Autostart a launchfile after/while boot](http://answers.ros.org/question/52044/autostart-a-launchfile-afterwhile-boot/) question and the accepted answer.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Praseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5042/praseen/) on 2013-08-30**:
will update after I try it